# formatting the dollar sign and the decimal alignment

Tags: python, formatting, format, alignment, decimal

Hi I'm new to python and have been playing around on python for a while but I still can't get the dollar sign and the decimal to align.

```
cost=pack*price

discount= cost * dis #the percent discount
amountdue = discount + cost #how much they owe


print(format("Total $", "13"), format(cost,"6.2f"))
print(format("Dis $", "13"), format(discount,"6.2f"))
print(format("Amount Due: $","13"),format(amountdue, "6.2f"))
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Total        $ XXXX.XX
Dis          $   XX.XX
Amount Due:  $ XXXX.XX
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the new formatting style:

```
print("{:<13}$ {:>7.2f}".format("Total", 7.34))
print("{:<13}$ {:>7.2f}".format("Dis", 7.34))
print("{:<13}$ {:>7.2f}".format("Amount Due:", 7.34))
# Total        $    7.34
# Dis          $    7.34
# Amount Due:  $    7.34
```